# How to get count of each unique firebase child so only the developer can see (not the user)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to figure out a way to get a list of each unique child in my Firebase Database & get a count of each unique child.

So for example if somebody entered Amazon 5 times an Hulu 2 times. I want to be able to know that. However, I don't want the user to know this.

I had a few ideas on how to do this.

**Idea 1**

Use Firebase's:

```
Answers.logCustomEvent...
```

However, I see two flaws with this idea.

**Flaw 1:** This wouldn't be useful for data that has already been entered.

**Flaw 2**: A user could enter Amason on accident and then changes it later to be the correct Amazon. I would get the incorrect entry..I could log changes but then I'd get bad data...or at least confusing data.

**Idea 2**

I could write a function inside of the app that could do this, but like I said. I don't need this functionality in the app for the user. I want it so I can know which sites I need to add functionality for first over ones that are seldom entered.

However, is it possible to have 2 apps that use the same database? So the main app is able to read and write data. While I could create a simple app that I wouldn't publish, only really use for myself that could Read the data but not write to it...

I tried to make my Database flat as I knew how..

When a user adds a service it doesn't go under the user node, I have a child called "services" and I just reference that service child in the "user" child.

So my database looks like this

```
cards
    card uid 1
        cardname: ""
        services
            service uid 1: true

services
    service uid 1
        serviceName: Amazon
        serviceUrl: ""

    service uid 2 
        serviceName: Amazon

users
    ... reference the card this user has access to
```

So to repeat the question.

I want to be able to know each unique serviceName and if there are duplicates of the same one..how many there are..

I don't need to know who created it or when..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may have another table where you have objects with only 2 fields: serviceName and count.

So, everytime you have a new instance, you check if it already persists in your table and increment the count value, otherwise create a new row.

Users will not see that info.

And, yes, you can access one database from several apps. Just get clientID, trackingID, etc...